# Show that $x^{(k)} \not\to x$ in the $l_\infty$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Given a fixed element $x\in l_1$, show that $x^{(k)} = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k,0,0,\ldots,0)$ converges to $x$ in the $l_1$ norm. Show that $x^{(k)} \to x$ in the $l_2$ norm as well. Produce a counterexample to show that $x^{(k)}\not\to x$ in the $l_\infty$ norm.

I'm struggling with the last part, i.e. the counterexample. I am showing my work for the remaining parts:

$$y_k = \|x-x^{(k)}\|_1 = \sum_{i=k+1}^\infty |x_i - x^{(k)}_i|$$
and
$$z_k = \|x-x^{(k)}\|_2 = \left(\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty |x_i - x^{(k)}_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$$

Clearly $y_k,z_k$ are decreasing and non-negative, so $y_k \stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ and $z_k \stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

I don't know how to proceed in the $l_\infty$ norm case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint:** maybe you can get $x^{(k)}$ not to converge at all and therefore it especially can't converge to $x$.

**possible solution:**

> Take $x = (1,1,1,\ldots) \in \ell^\infty$. Now
>  \begin{align*} \|x^{(N)}-x^{(M)}\|_\infty = 1 \end{align*}
>  for all $M,N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $M > N$. This means $x^{(k)}$ is not a cauchy sequence and therefore it cannot converge.

**edit:**
If you had $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^{1}$ you would get $|x_n| \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and therefore
$$
\|x-x^{(k)}\|_\infty = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N},\ n>k} |x_n| \to 0
$$
as $k\to\infty$ so you wouldn't be able to find a counterexample. Phrased in other words your statement also holds for the space $(c_0, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ of sequences that converge to 0.

Regarding your proofs of the other statements: A real sequence being decreasing and non-negative isn't enough for convergence to 0 (take for example $1+\frac 1 n$), but I think you know that and just phrased it wrong. It probably becomes clearer if you just take a power:
$$
\|x-x^{(k)}\|_{\ell^p}^p = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty |x_n|^p \to 0
$$
as $k\to\infty$ for $p\in [1,\infty[$.

Comment: Ohh, I see! So $x\in l_\infty$. I was thinking $x\in l_1$. Would my proof with the $l_2$ norm actually go wrong if I assume $x\in l_1$, by the way? I think now I understand that for each of the three cases I should have taken $x\in l_1,l_2,l_\infty$ respectively. Correct?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine I added some more explanation. I don't see anything that would go wrong if you take $x\in\ell^1$ for your $\ell^2$ norm, but that probably isn't what you want to show...

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine another node to my last comment: one can show that $\ell^1 \subseteq \ell^2$, but for example $(\frac 1 n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \in \ell^2 \setminus \ell^1$, so taking $x\in\ell^1$ technically wouldn't suffice to prove it in all generality but the proof would stay the same anyways